# parse string from webAPI into multiple variables for openlayers GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3, geojson

currently my webAPI method returns to me a long string for a GeoJSON layer that i need to parse through and separate out into mutliple variables that allows for me to create my necessary GeoJSON layer. Can i accomplish this easily through the str.split function or is a there another route that i need to take

The returned string from the webAPI looks like this:

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection","bbox":[1108864.9370570681,507099.9482870581,1109064.5346246646,507455.89728260477],"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1109035.4443840273,507308.60334444791],[1108893.4509952962,507307.23951566964],[1108893.1628068388,507337.23816090077],[1109035.1562700756,507338.60198967904],[1109035.4443840273,507308.60334444791]]]},"properties":{"twp":"01","map_num":"8.0","sec":"33.00","qtr_sec":"003","map_block":"007","parcel":"008.00","pid":"018.033.00003007008.00","gis_acres":"0.0977962","debbie_ac":"0.10c","misc":"","scan_deeds":"T:\\Images\\Hyperlinked_Deeds\\00203","latitude":"37.2227488237","longitude":"-89.5082666075","name":"O'RILEY PROPERTIES LLC","site_addre":"519 MADISON ST","shape_leng":"344.000009295","shape_area":"4260.00340015","card_ac":"0.00c 0.00d","date":"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM","ParcelId":"203","ParcelNumber":"0180330000300700800","_hg_layer":"PARCELS"}}
```

The features section of the string has an array of features but for use in this example i only copied of one specific feature that. the format I'm looking to set this up in is as follows:

```
    var geojsonObject = {
'type': 'FeatureCollection',
'crs': {
    'type': 'name',
    'properties': {
        //'name': 'EPSG:3857'
    }
},

'features': [

    {
        "type": "Feature", "geometry":
           {
               "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[1109035.4443840273, 507308.60334444791],
                                              [1108893.4509952962, 507307.23951566964],
                                               [1108893.1628068388, 507337.23816090077],
                                               [1109035.1562700756, 507338.60198967904],
                                               [1109035.4443840273, 507308.60334444791]]]
               , "properties": {
                   "twp": "01",
                   "map_num": "8.0",
                   "sec": "33.00",
                   "qtr_sec": "003",
                   "map_block": "007",
                   "parcel": "008.00",
                   "pid": "018.033.00003007008.00",
                   "gis_acres": "0.0977962",
                   "debbie_ac": "0.10c",
                   "misc": "",
                   "scan_deeds": "T:\\Images\\Hyperlinked_Deeds\\00203",
                   "latitude": "37.2227488237",
                   "longitude": "-89.5082666075",
                   "name": "O'RILEY PROPERTIES LLC",
                   "site_addre": "519 MADISON ST",
                   "shape_leng": "344.000009295",
                   "shape_area": "4260.00340015",
                   "card_ac": "0.00c 0.00d",
                   "date": "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM",
                   "ParcelId": "203",
                   "ParcelNumber": "0180330000300700800",
                   "_hg_layer": "PARCELS"
               }
           }
    }
```

Again the features section of this code in my example just shows one specific feature but i will actually have several features that i need to display.

is parsing through this long string the easiest route to go or do i need to restructure the string that my WebAPI actually sends back to me

Comment: JSON.parse() should handle this for you if it's a valid JSON response.

Comment: thanks worked perfectly